# Is it possible to have an SQL table with over a million columns?

Tags: sql, limit, database

I am building a database for microarray data. Each patient sample has over 1,000,000 features and I would like to store the patient samples as rows in an SQL table with each feature as a column.

```
                 HuEX Microarray Data
+----+----------+----------+-----+------------------+
| ID | Feature1 | Feature2 | ... | Feature1,000,000 |
+----+----------+----------+-----+------------------+
| 1  |   2.3543 |  10.5454 | ... |          5.34333 |
| 2  |  13.4312 |   1.3432 | ... |         40.23422 |
+----+----------+----------+-----+------------------+
```

I know most relational database systems have limits on the number of columns in a table.

```
+------------+-----------------+
|       DBMS | Max Table Col # | 
+------------+-----------------+
| SQL Server |  1,024 - 30,000 |
|      MySQL |    65,535 bytes |
| PostgreSQL |     250 - 1,600 |
|     Oracle |           1,000 | 
+------------+-----------------+
```

Obviously these limitations are too low for my task. Is there anyway to increase the number of columns an SQL database table can have or is there another DBMS that can handle such high number of table columns?

**Update**

Note all the columns will have values for all the rows.

Comment: Do you really collect a million data points on each patient, or is more like a few hundred out of a possible 1 million

Comment: [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) is what you are looking for

Comment: @ Conrad, I am working with human expression microarrays which have over a million probesets per array (chip). This is a bit technical, but basically this means our samples have over 1 million features all having values (numeric doubles).

Comment: @Nixuz If it's not sparse data (I was original assuming it was so before!), perhaps just store the data in an appropriate *de-normalized form*, depending upon the exact access requirements. E.g. single blob, blob by block range, XML (can be queried in some DBs, fsvo queried), pre-extracted statistics, etc. Also, because this is so specialized, a RDBMS might *not* be the best way to store it -- again, depends upon access requirements.

Comment: @ pst: Yes, using blobs is a possible solution, but due to how restricted it makes accessing individual features for sample sets it makes our analysis process more complicated.

Comment: @Nixuz I don't think there will necessarily be an easy way -- I'd start with determining the required access/query use-cases and then seeing how that can be implemented with the least amount of pain ;-) A hybrid may be to split each result in multiple records of say, 1000 homogenous values along with the segment number. (Makes for only one 1000 records per CPU, not 1000000 and should be relatively query-able -- just include segment number as well.)

Answer (score 13):

Don't.

Event if you can make it work, it will be very slow and unwieldly.

Instead, you should make a separate table with columns for `PatientID`, `Feature`, and `Value`.
This table would have one row for each cell in your proposed table.

It also makes it possible to add additional information about each patient-feature pair.

Comment: I had thought of doing this, but it seems like a bad idea. First it is not as easy to work with, and secondly if I want to query for all the features of all the patients in one of my datasets I will end up with 80,000,000 rows. My guess is that it will be very very slow. What do you think?

Comment: @Nixuz: This should be both faster and easier to work with than your model.

Comment: @Nixuz: But check what indexes you'll have to add **before** running queries in a 80M+ rows table.

Answer (score 4):

You'd normally split (normalize) the tables:

```
Sample: ID, PatientID
Feature: ID, Name
SampleFeature: SampleID, FeatureID, value
```

SQL databases can't handle a lot of columns, but they can handle a lot of rows.

Answer (score 4):

Try rearranging your table to:

```
CREATE TABLE MicroarrayData (
    SampleID  INTEGER,
    FeatureID INTEGER,
    Value     REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SampleID, FeatureID)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a use case for an [Entity-Attribute-Value Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (EAV), and may actually be better suited to *non* RDBMS/SQL solutions in some intense environments. (Relational database are workhorses though ... might as well use one until it's provably not sufficient ;-)

From the Wikipedia article:

> > Entity-attribute-value model (EAV) is a data model to describe entities where the number of attributes (properties, parameters) that can be used to describe them is potentially vast, but the number that will actually apply to a given entity is relatively modest. In mathematics, this model is known as a sparse matrix.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Well, going with the new information that this is *dense array* of homogenous numeric (double) values and querying is important (that is, I will disregard de-normalization into blobs/XML and the use of special UDFs), I propose the following:

Split each result into multiple records, where each record is of the form:

```
ID, SEGMENT, IDx ... // where x is [0, q]
```

The value of `q` is arbitrary but should be chosen based upon particular database implementation (e.g. try to fit into the 8k record size in SQL Server) for performance/efficiency reasons.

Each result will then be split into the records such that `SEGMENT` refers to the segment. That is the "absolute index" of a given feature is `n = SEGMENT * q + x` and feature `n` will be found in the record where `SEGMENT = n / q`. It then follows that the Primary Key is `(ID, SEGMENT)`.

Thus querying is still easy -- the only change is the conversion to/from the segment -- with the only additional requirement being the `SEGMENT` (this column may also participate in an index).

(A separate table can be used to map features to `SEGMENT/x` or otherwise. In this way it is similar to an EAV Model.)

Thus, while similar in some ways to a fully normlized form it takes advantage of the packed/homogenous/static-feature nature of the initial matrix to significantly reduce the number of records -- while 2 million records is an arguably small table and 20 million records is only a "mid-sized" table, 200 million records (results from 200 chips x 1 million features per chip, if each feature results in a record) starts to become daunting. While the same complexity, a `q` of 200 would reduce the number of records to a mere 10 million. (Each compacted record is also *much* more efficient in terms of data/structure ratio.)

Happy coding.

---

While the above is one tentative "what if" suggestion on my part, I would encourage exploring the problem more -- in particular, the exact data-access patterns required. I'm not sure this is a "typical" usage of a standard RDBMS and an RDBMS may not even be a good way to approach this problem.